# Calculating Distance with PHP for multiple points

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am fetching data from a MySQL database using AJAX/jQuery and then doing some calculations (distance between co-ordinates) on client-side. I found that this is quite taxing on the browser and would like to rather do this on the server-side.

My returned JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    ["148", "osmand", "2", "2016-03-26 13:48:04", "2016-03-26 13:48:01", "2016-03-26 13:48:01", "1", "-39.094856", "46.166472", "1432.7", "0", "0", "20 Maretha street", "{\"battery\":\"0\",\"ip\":\"105.5.117.20\"}"],
    ["149", "osmand", "2", "2016-03-26 13:48:24", "2016-03-26 13:48:22", "2016-03-26 13:48:22", "1", "-39.099305", "46.162392", "1435.26", "0", "0", "7 Ernst street", "{\"battery\":\"0\",\"ip\":\"105.5.117.20\"}"],
    ["150", "osmand", "2", "2016-03-26 13:48:45", "2016-03-26 13:48:43", "2016-03-26 13:48:43", "1", "-39.099305", "46.162392", "1435.62", "0", "0", "7 Ernst street", "{\"battery\":\"0\",\"ip\":\"105.5.117.20\"}"],
  ],
  "errors": false
}
```

The seventh and eighth values are the co-ordinates. I am currently calculating the distance by plotting the co-ordinates and then drawing a polyline and then calculating the distance of the polyline in leaflet.

I however found some sample PHP code that calculates distance between two points:

```
class test {

public function GetDistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {
        $radLat1 = $lat1*3.1415926535898/180.0;
        $radLat2 = $lat2*3.1415926535898/180.0;
        $a = $radLat1 - $radLat2;
        $b = ($lng1*3.1415926535898/180.0) - ($lng2*3.1415926535898/180.0);
        $s = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($a / 2), 2) + cos($radLat1) * cos($radLat2) * pow(sin($b / 2), 2)));
        $s = $s * 6378.137; // EARTH_RADIUS;
        $s = round($s * 1000,3); 
        return $s;
    }       
}
```

**usage example**

```
$obj=new test();
$dis=$obj->GetDistance($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2);
```

My PHP code currently looks like this:

```
<?php
    $inputvalues = $_POST;
    $errors = false;
    $result = false;
    include_once 'database.php';

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    foreach ($inputvalues as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $inputvalues[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $value );
        } else {
            $errors[$key] = 'The field '.$key.' is empty';
        }
    }

if( !$errors ) {
        $addresult = "
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE `fixtime` BETWEEN '" . $inputvalues['start'] . "' AND '" . $inputvalues['end'] . "' AND deviceid='" . $inputvalues['deviceid'] . "'
         ";
         if( $result = $mysqli->query($addresult) ) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_all())
            {
                $returnResult = $row;
            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

    exit;
?>
```

How can I implement this into my code? I don't know how to get the co-ordinates from the mysql result, do the calculation for each co-ordinate and then output it via JSON.

Sorry if this is a basic or broad question, I am very new to PHP and i'm still learning.

Comment: You mean calculating the distance between each point to every other point? This will be very costly, regardless of where you're doing this - on the client or on the server. (depending on the number of points, of course) A distance from single point (e.g., your current location) to a list of points is a different matter, which one are you after?

Comment: Is this for navigation? The generic earth radius will not give you correct result if so. Ideally create a mxn matrix of distance by using Goolge API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: From point A to point B to point C etc for the returned results.

Comment: @Shailesh Yes, it is for navigation. I am using leaflet and I saw that the Matrix API has a lot of usage restrictions so I can't use it unfortunately. My locations are sent every 10 seconds so I was hoping since the frequency is high, so will the accuracy.

Comment: Just create a table with columns to, from, distance. Use Goolge API to add initial result. Update this table once you need to change anything. Google give walking/driving distance, which is very useful as the distance calculated between entrance point or last point where vehicle can go.

Comment: I am creating a table of all returned points. If I use the distance matrix api, does 1 request mean distance between two points or if I have 100 points and I want the total distance, is that 100 requests?

Answer (score 0):

This is my function which save results in intermediate files. I am not sure if it will work for you but could be helpful. Update MY_KEY and mode for use.

```
function get_distance($locations, $locs){
    $location_distance = array();
    foreach($locations as $location_key=>$location){
        $locs_keys = array_keys($locs);
        $loc_lat_lng = "$location[1],$location[2]";
        $locs_lat_lng = join('|',$locs_keys);
        $path = './'.$location_key;
        if(!file_exists($path)){
            $path = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$loc_lat_lng&destinations=$locs_lat_lng&mode=walking&key=MY_KEY";
        }
        $map_data = file_get_contents($path);
        if($path != './'.$location_key){
            file_put_contents('./'.$location_key, $map_data);
        }
        $map_data = json_decode($map_data, true);
        $distance = reslove_distance($map_data);
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($distance); $i++){
            $location_distance[$location_key][$locs_keys[$i]] = $distance[$i];
        }
    }
    return $location_distance;
}

function reslove_distance($map_data=null){
    $distance = array();
    foreach($map_data['rows'][0]['elements'] as $element){
        $distance[] =  (int)$element['distance']['value'];
    }
    return $distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    function getDistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $distance_unit = 'km')
    {
        $multiplicator = ($distance_unit == 'km' ? 6371 : 3959);

        $lat1_rad = deg2rad($lat1);
        $lng1_rad = deg2rad($lng1);
        $lat2_rad = deg2rad($lat2);
        $lng2_rad = deg2rad($lng2);

        return $multiplicator * acos(cos($lat1_rad) * cos($lat2_rad) * cos($lng2 - $lng1) + sin($lat1_rad) * sin($lat2));
    }
```

And then when you're fetching the results from database:

```
    $entries = $result->fetch_all();

    foreach ($entries as $index => &$entry) {
        if ($index < count($entries)) {
            $next = $entries[$index + 1];

            $entry['distance'] = self::getDistance($entry['latitude'], $entry['longitude'], $next['latitude'], $next['longitude']);
        } else {
            $entry['distance'] = 0; // there is no "next" point to calculate the distance.
        }
    }
```

This should give you an array where each entry contains the distance to the next point

Answer (score 0):

Let me try with my case

```
$myLoc = ["X", -7.699362, 112.973617, "origin"];
$otherLoc = [
["A", -7.683493, 112.958725, "empty"],
["B", -7.679341, 112.976363, "full"],
["C", -7.702259, 112.983058, "full"],
["D", -7.689507, 113.011858, "empty"],
["E", -7.723439, 112.969114, "empty"],
["F", -7.693207, 112.938988, "full"]
];

function distance($myLoc, $otherLoc)
{
$theta = array();
$dist = array();
$km = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($otherLoc); $i++) {
    if (($myLoc[1] == $otherLoc[$i][1]) && ($myLoc[2] == $otherLoc[$i][2])) {
        return 0;
    }
    $theta[] = $myLoc[2] - $otherLoc[$i][2];
    $dist[] = sin(deg2rad($myLoc[1])) * sin(deg2rad($otherLoc[$i][1])) +  cos(deg2rad($myLoc[1])) * cos(deg2rad($otherLoc[$i][1])) * cos(deg2rad($theta[$i]));
    $dist_a[] = acos($dist[$i]);
    $dist_b[] = rad2deg($dist_a[$i]);
    $km[] = round(($dist_b[$i] * 60 * 1.1515) * 1.609344, 1);
}
return $km;
}

$result = distance($myLoc, $fullStatus);
// sort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

You just need it hehehe